# My drop down menu is not working properly in my blogger template, child items are not shown

Tags: css

outside of blogger template it works fine, but in blogger template it does not show child items, please help me.
my css code is given below

[image]

---

/* Pure CSS3 Multi Level Drop Down Navigation Menu */
/*             By www.Bloggermint.com            */

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WOjf.jpg):

```css
#nav {
  float: left;
  font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #121314;
  border-top: 1px solid #2b2e30;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

#nav ul li a {
  float: left;
  color: #d4d4d4;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #3C4042;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(59, 63, 65)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(72, 76, 77)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(75, 77, 77)));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59, 63, 65) 9%, rgb(72, 76, 77) 55%, rgb(75, 77, 77) 78%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59, 63, 65) 9%, rgb(72, 76, 77) 55%, rgb(75, 77, 77) 78%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#nav ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li:hover>a {
  color: #252525;
  background: #3C4042;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77, 79, 79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67, 70, 71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69, 70, 71)));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77, 79, 79) 9%, rgb(67, 70, 71) 55%, rgb(69, 70, 71) 78%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77, 79, 79) 9%, rgb(67, 70, 71) 55%, rgb(69, 70, 71) 78%);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 -1px #000;
}

#nav li ul a:hover,
#nav ul li li:hover>a {
  color: #2c2c2c;
  background: #5C9ACD;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.17, rgb(61, 111, 177)), color-stop(0.51, rgb(80, 136, 199)), color-stop(1, rgb(92, 154, 205)));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61, 111, 177) 17%, rgb(80, 136, 199) 51%, rgb(92, 154, 205) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61, 111, 177) 17%, rgb(80, 136, 199) 51%, rgb(92, 154, 205) 100%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-top: 1px solid #7BAED9;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

#nav li ul {
  background: #3C4042;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77, 79, 79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67, 70, 71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69, 70, 71)));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77, 79, 79) 9%, rgb(67, 70, 71) 55%, rgb(69, 70, 71) 78%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77, 79, 79) 9%, rgb(67, 70, 71) 55%, rgb(69, 70, 71) 78%);
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  left: -999em;
  margin: 35px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#nav li:hover ul {
  left: auto;
}

#nav li ul a {
  background: none;
  border: 0 none;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 120px;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

#nav li li ul {
  margin: -1px 0 0 160px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#nav li li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
}

#nav ul ul li:last-child>a {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

#nav ul ul ul li:first-child>a {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Our Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">One Dropdown</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.4</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Level 2.5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three Levels</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.3</a>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.5</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2.3.7</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2.5</a></li>
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your website, its because of some `blogger` CSS overriding the navbar CSS, the blogger is setting the `ul` tag to `overflow:hidden` which is hiding the second dropdown. If you change the below line you can see the different levels being visible!

**CSS:**

```
#nav li ul {
  overflow: visible;
  background: #3C4042;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77, 79, 79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67, 70, 71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69, 70, 71)));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77, 79, 79) 9%, rgb(67, 70, 71) 55%, rgb(69, 70, 71) 78%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77, 79, 79) 9%, rgb(67, 70, 71) 55%, rgb(69, 70, 71) 78%);
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  left: -999em;
  margin: 35px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much Mr. Naren Murali,

Comment: May you live long.

Comment: Naren Bhai can i ask something else?

Comment: @Faisal Yes, tell me

Comment: I added one more child item in my second child item, it show automatically when i hover on second child item,

Comment: please send me third child item hover coding that make him hidden, and shows when i hover on it, don't show automatically

Comment: @Faisal Need some time, let me get back to you

Comment: OK, brother i'm waiting for you, please reply soon